# how to make template alias as template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, using

I have tried template,and syntax of template class is charming for me,
I could thought of the way how to poorly practice std::function at the time.

but ... how about function pointer?
It seems should format them into managable template type,
which is better because of funcion pointer usually could only be indirect declare.

`fptr<int()> array_of_main[42];`

so I tried something below:

```
template<class T,class... U>
using fptr<T(U...)>=auto (*)(U...)->T;
```

it fails,it seems like compiler do not template specialization on alias.
Another attampt is:

```
template<class T,class... U>
using fptr=auto (*)(U...)->T;

auto main()->int
{
    fptr<int,int> a[7];
    fptr<void,int> b[7];
}
```

well,not good,I still cannot declare fptr which parameter is empty.
and former attampt has showing us specialization not really work on this.

so ,how to make `fptr<int,void>` and `fptr<void,void>` possible?
could template specialization work on "using"keyword?
and why "In substitution of template" void could not apply to `U...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have `fptr<int()>` syntax, in fact, you just have to add pointer...

```
template <typename Sig>
using fptr = Sig*;
```

Your partial specialization might be done on classes though:

```
template <typename Sig> struct fptr_helper;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args> struct fptr_helper<Ret(Args...)>
{
    using type = Ret(*)(Args...);
};
// C-ellipsis case as printf
template <typename Ret, typename... Args> struct fptr_helper<Ret(Args..., ...)>
{
    using type = Ret(*)(Args..., ...);
};
template <typename Sig> using fptr = typename fptr_helper<Sig>::type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly fine. It's

```
fptr<int,void>
fptr<void,void>
```

That is wrong. If you want pointer to function with no parameters then do this:

```
fptr<int>
fptr<void>
```

---

May I suggest an alternate approach using only standard library:

```
std::add_pointer_t<int(int)> a[7];
std::add_pointer_t<void(int)> b[7];
std::add_pointer_t<int()> c[7];
std::add_pointer_t<void()> d[7];
```

Or since C++20:

```
std::type_identity_t<int (*) (int)> a[7];
std::type_identity_t<void (*) (int)> b[7];
std::type_identity_t<int (*) ()> c[7];
std::type_identity_t<void (*) ()> d[7];
```